# Report on user who converted lead

Tags: reporting, leads

How do you create a report that shows which user converted a lead? I want to know who clicked the Convert button on the lead. Marketing creates the lead and then we have sales development that work leads and assign Hot leads to sales managers. I need to run reports on how many leads each inside rep converts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do the following:

- New Report - Choose Leads with converted Lead Info - this will only be converted leads
- Add column: Last Modified By - this will be the user that converted the Lead

Comment: Note that this is only correct if nobody in your org has permissions to edit converted Leads.

Comment: @CharlesT - very true.  I suppose one could use analytic snapshots to capture daily summaries and mitigate effects of said sysad